MQTT client subscriber : How to break a loop by receiving a new message from a publisher?
Can someone help me on that ?
I try to break a timelapse (written as looping a function) on my RPI started with a message "StartScanning", by receiving a "Quit" message.
I am sorry for my knowledge on programming, but I am really stuck at this last step!
Here the code block of the subscriber ( which is the RPI and its PiCamera )
import time
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from picamera import PiCamera
import subprocess
import pathlib


import socket

camera = PiCamera()

Broker = "192.168.1.100"
Port = 1883

# topics
pub_topic = "DIC/scanning"
sub_topic = "DIC/keyboard"



# on connect
def on_connect(mqttc, obj, flags, reason_code):
    print(f"rc :" + str(reason_code))
    mqttc.subscribe(sub_topic)
    
# on message
def on_message(mqttc, obj, msg):
    print(str(msg.topic) + " " +  str(msg.qos) + " " + str(msg.payload))
        
    if msg.payload.decode() == "StartScanning":
        while True:
             timelapse()
    elif msg.payload.decode() == "Quit" :
        timelapse.hasbeencalled=False
            

#fonction scanning avec timelapse
def timelapse():
    hostName = socket.gethostname()
    pathlib.Path('/home/pi/Desktop/DIC_' + hostName).mkdir(parents=True,exist_ok=True)
    fileName= datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H-%M-%S-%f")+".jpg"
    camera.resolution = (2592, 1944) #picture resolution
    camera.capture('/home/pi/Desktop/DIC_' + hostName + '/' + fileName)
    #camera.capture('/home/pi/Desktop/DIC_RPI1/RPI1_' + fileName)
    sleep(1)


#on subscribe
def on_subscribe(mqttc, obj, mid, reason_code_list):
    print("Subscribed: " + str(mid) + " " + str(reason_code_list))
    
    
#on log
def on_log(mqttc, obj, level, string):
    print(string)
    
# on publish
def on_publish(mqttc, obj, mid):
    print(f"risposta inviata con message  id:" + str(mid))
    
# connect MQTT client
mqttc = mqtt.Client() #(mqtt.CallbackAPIVersion.VERSION1)

mqttc.on_subscribe = on_subscribe
mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
mqttc.on_message = on_message
mqttc.on_publish = on_publish

mqttc.connect("192.168.1.100", 1883, 60)
#mqttc.subscribe(sub_topic)

mqttc.loop_forever()


I tried to insert inside the function timelapse() a ' while msg.payload=="StartScanning": ' but it didn't work.
I also tried to publish the 2 messages "StartScanning" and "Quit" on two topics and subscribe o them, but since the loop function runs, I can't receive other message from a publisher.

when you run while True then it may block all code. It may need to run timelapse in separate thread or process. And it may need to run while True  inside timelapse with extra while running: And this thread may need to use queue to get message and change running

Thank you very much for your time and answer. I will implement your idea and try the script you wrote. I will come back to you as soon as I try it ! ;)

while True (or any long-running code) blocks your code and it can't get messages.
You have to run timelapse (with while-loop) in separate thread, and it needs queue to get messages which can control while-loop
def timelapse(queue):
    while True:
        if not queue.empty():
            message = queue.get()
            if message == 'quit':
                break  # exit `while`-loop and finish thread

        # ... your code ...
        sleep(1)

if msg.payload.decode() == "StartScanning":
    global queue # inform function that it has to keep it as global variable
    queue = queue.Queue()
    thread.Thread(targe=timelapse, args=(queue,) ).start()  # it has to be comma in `(queue,)`
   
if msg.payload.decode() == "Quit":
    queue.put('quit')

